# Why would a function keyword not be recognized inside a <script type="text/javascript"> tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating an emailing function on a website. The concept is that a button will automatically send an attachment to a pre-programmed email address, but the script cannot recognize the "function" keyword as such and treats it as plain text. I am doing it with SMTPJS and this is the code:

```
<Divider type="vertical" />

<input type="button" value={"Send Email"} onClick="sendEmail()"></input>
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js" type="text/javascript">
  function sendEmail() {
    Email.send({
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
      Username: "email@gmail.com",
      Password: "password",
      To: 'email2@gmail.com',
      From: "email@gmail.com",
      Subject: "This is the subject",
      Body: "And this is the body",
      Attachments: [{
        name: "smtpjs.png",
        path: "https://networkprogramming.files.wordpress.com/2017/11/smtpjs.png"
      }]
    }).then(
      message => alert(message)
    )
  };
</script>
```

The precedent I am finding for SMPTJS use a classic HTML document layout with a head and body, but I need this to be just another element - i.e. a button with a script on the webpage in the context of a larger ReactJS file and I am not getting why the function doesn't register, even with the type defined in the source. I haven't been able to find this particular issue in SO or the wider interwebs, neither, and it doesn't appear to be a spelling issue, but it might be a syntax one. For more context:

[image]\

Error that comes up:

[image]

Any insight will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Correcting the  tag syntax still does not make the function appear as such:

[image]

What will make the function appear is removing the close of the  tag, which makes the entire section invalid:

[image]

Can this be an issue with JS itself, or some problem with the particular release version?!

**UPDATE:**

If I add the stmp.js file to the project and import it:

[image]

the following errors appear about the library file:

[image]

It feels like a catch-22.

Comment: Generally you use `<script src="somewhere"></script>` with nothing between the tags to source a js file _**OR**_ use `<script>some code here</script>` to put the code inline — you're doing both in the same tag. I haven't tested that, but I wouldn't expect it to work.

Comment: so this snippet is from a react application? I haven't seen this before so: are you sure there are `<script>` tags in react?

Comment: What's the `react` relationship with this question?

Comment: @bastianowicz That's not usual, but I've added react to an existing web app and had existing inline `<script>` tags that still worked.

Comment: @Stephen, yes - the multiple arguments inside the src tag is illegal; 

bastianowics, script tags in react are a thing and do work, as far as I've seen (being generally new to JS myself); 

spender - the context of this page is a collection of listed properties whose components are built with react (fragment, etc...) and html is used for calling particular functions, though not necessarily with the script method.

Comment: The errors you show here don't say that the function keyword isn't recognized; the errors refer to `Email`. where is `Email` defined? In smtp.js? Is that file being loaded correctly?

Comment: I added the js file of the lib to the project and imported Email from it, but that leads to a separate set of errors in that file itself, which should not be necessary, if the scr makes a reference to it, anyway. Do I need to declare it as an instance of that 
smtp "class", like in Java?

Comment: I'm not familiar with importing/exporting in JS, but I don't think you'd need to import `Email` to use it, nor would you be able to unless if it was exported in the smtp.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have *both* an `src` in a `<script>` tag and code.  It's either one or the other.

Also, the `type` is not needed.

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
<script>
    function sendEmail() {}
</script>
```

Comment: You're right. Although, the function doesn't register even after the correction...will add an edit to the question to reflect